# Does fancyimpute's SoftImpute require normalized data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, imputation, fancyimpute

The page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute has the line

```
# Instead of solving the nuclear norm objective directly, instead
# induce sparsity using singular value thresholding
X_filled_softimpute = SoftImpute().complete(X_incomplete_normalized)
```

which kind of suggests that I need to normalize the input data. However I did not find any details on the internet, what exactly is meant by that. Do I have to normalize my data beforehand and what exactly is expected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should definitely normalize the data. Consider the following example:

```
from fancyimpute import SoftImpute
import numpy as np
v=np.random.normal(100,0.5,(5,3))
v[2,1:3]=np.nan
v[0,0]=np.nan
v[3,0]=np.nan
SoftImpute().complete(v)
```

The result is

```
array([[  81.78428587,   99.69638878,  100.67626769],
       [  99.82026281,  100.09077899,   99.50273223],
       [  99.70946085,   70.98619873,   69.57668189],
       [  81.82898539,   99.66269922,  100.95263318],
       [  99.14285815,  100.10809651,   99.73870089]])
```

Note that the places where I put `nan` are completely off. However, if instead you run

```
from fancyimpute import SoftImpute
import numpy as np
v=np.random.normal(0,1,(5,3))
v[2,1:3]=np.nan
v[0,0]=np.nan
v[3,0]=np.nan
SoftImpute().complete(v)
```

(same code as before, the only difference is that `v` is normalized) you get the following reasonable result:

```
array([[ 0.07705556, -0.53449412, -0.20081351],
       [ 0.9709198 , -1.19890962, -0.25176222],
       [ 0.41839224, -0.11786451,  0.03231515],
       [ 0.21374759, -0.66986997,  0.78565414],
       [ 0.30004524,  1.28055845,  0.58625942]])
```

Thus, when you are using `SoftImpute`, don't forget to normalize your data (you can do that by making the mean of every column to be 0, and the std to be 1).